# Certified Nvidia driver (from website) downloaded/installed and still doesnt support any graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I just installed the correct driver for my GeForce 6600 gt which is called x86. 
I had to run it through a ctrl-alt-f1 and stop x server. all went well, so i reboot and it looks like the driver is working (i had no drivers turned on when i ran this one), so all the open gl cairo dock was working well as usual and more. i downloaded hedgewars (worms) and flightgear, super choppy. AND trust me, its NOT my video card, they ran perfectly on pardus as well as HON.
Did i not install the driver correctly?
IF not PLEASE give me step by step instructions.

I enabled one of the proprietery drivers, rebooted, and now there is failure to boot, errors

```
Automatic crash report generation (FAIL) 
LightDm display manager (FAIL)
```

and it's unable to proceed, how do i disable all drivers within commands?

I haven't installed it using additional drivers, the default drivers that they gave me though, are incorrect. And I am unfamiliar with this program.

I disabled all of the proprietary drivers before i ran the install of the nvidia driver from the website, so the screen was glitchy and flickering (without driver) and then i ran the install through ctrl-alt-f1 and i rebooted after it said it was successful. And when it rebooted the screen was regular again and no flickers, but it doesn't run games

I still DON'T have the certified nvidia x86 driver under additional drivers.

Answer (score 2):

You should **not** install the drivers directly from nvidia.com as it's not fully compatible with Ubuntu. To recover from your mistake, uninstall the driver from nvidia.com first by opening a console and running:

```
sudo nvidia-installer --uninstall
```

Then reboot. If you still do not have your graphics effects back, open a console and run:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgl1-mesa-glx
```

To install the nvidia driver on Ubuntu, open the Additional Drivers program and choose the current driver.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed it using the program Additional driver, available under System Settings?
This is the official program to use to install proprietary drivers in Ubuntu. It recognizes your video cards and suggests you the driver/s to install for your hardware, such as video card, wifi, etc.

Comment: no i havent installed it using additional drivers, the default drivers that they gave me though, are incorrect. And i am unfamiliar with this program

Comment: i downloaded and installed the nvidia driver, i was expecting it to "pop up" in the additional driver section, i dont know how to activate the driver i installed, i also dont know were to find it.

Comment: the odd thing is, i disabled all of the proprietary drivers before i ran the install of the nvidia driver from the website, so the screen was glitchy and flickering (without driver) and then i ran the intall through ctrl-alt-f1 and i rebooted after it said it was successful. And when it rebooted the screen was regular agin and no flickers, but it doesnt run games!?!? somethigns wrong

Comment: Try to install the driver from that program. When you open it, it will show the right driver for your Nvidia driver. Click on Activate and, after the end of the installation of the driver, it will ask you to reboot and then the driver will be installed.

Comment: ill try all of the proprietary and ill let you know if any work, but i still DONT have the certified nvidia x86 driver under additional drivers.