# How do I remove the driver installed from nvidia.com?

Tags: nvidia

I have updated my graphics card with  NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-295.20 driver and since then the screen turns white with black vertical lines at startup, shootoff and reboot.

Since then I have tryed to change it with the drivers at "Alternative Drivers" and none of them works right, the  same bug happens.

What can I do to solve this issue.

Thank you

Comment: What graphics card do you have? Before installing the nvidia-current driver, be sure to remove the OLD one (installed using the .sh file) first. Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/92587/6969

Comment: Great, I had such trouble finding this. Thank you for using nvidia.com in your title!

Answer (score 3):

- Hold shift during boot and choose recovery mode option
- Choose netroot.
- Uninstall nvidia:

`nvidia-uninstall`

- Remove the nvidia configuration file:

`rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

- Reinstall the Gl Mesa package:

`apt-get --reinstall install libgl1-mesa-glx`

- Reboot with:

`reboot`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, where is that documented?