# Ubuntu is 13.04 slower than 12

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, upgrade, performance

I've been using Ubuntu for quite a while now, mostly 12.
I recently updated to Ubuntu 13.04 and the most noticeable change is that it's overall slower than 12. In particular, moving windows on the screen is very jerky. I tried several "graphics card driver" options, including downloading the graphics card driver directly from the Nvidia website without success.

Do you have any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: any measurement? Could be subjective feeling or reason of installed software, memory limit reached etc...

Comment: Nothing changed beside the system itself (and the video driver): same hardware, same software. I have 16G of RAM (of which 4G is free) and the system is installed on a SSD.

Comment: it is not the same software. It is ubuntu 13 instead of 12. Find your bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just only about videocard, try to remove nvidia drivers and install it again. Can be kernel vs nvidia troubles (there are lot of them).

If your drivers are installed from repository, try this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

after reboot try to install additional nvidia drivers from repository.

If you have installed your drivers via shell script, then uninstall it ([How do I remove the driver installed from nvidia.com?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113566/how-do-i-remove-the-driver-installed-from-nvidia-com)) and then try to use additional drivers from repository.